# elementary OS stuck on loading screen

Tags: release-freya

After installing elementary OS Freya x64 I updated it and installed AMD graphics drivers. After rebooting everything worked fine, but later I installed some programs and now Freya freezes on loading screen everytime I try to boot.

When I press `ctrl+alt+f1` there is no error message and when I press `f2` I see some system messages, but eventually it stops and then nothing happens. There doesn't seem to be any error and it doesn't always stop at exactly the same point but it's always after "System V runlevel compatibility".

I can only go to recovery mode and drop to root shell, but I don't know what to do there to fix my system. Could it be something wrong with AMD drivers? Please help.

Comment: These are two places where you could look for something that might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/184411/stuck-on-stopping-system-v-runlevel-compatibility, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1807612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled AMD graphics driver, which I downloaded from AMD website and everything works fine. I still don't know what caused the issue, but it's fixed.

Edit: I found out that the issue may be caused by AMD drivers which break after kernel upgrades. It's possible that upgrading kernel to newer version and installing AMD open source drivers could fix this issue
https://allienworks.net/2015/elementary-os-freya-amd-drivers/